# How to check if a date time is between multiple time spans?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a cell that contains multiple time spans in the following format:

`2024-03-20 15:00:00&2024-03-20 16:00:00|2024-03-20 20:15:00&2024-03-21 15:00:00|...`

I want to check if a particular date time e.g. `2024-03-20 16:30:00` falls in any of those ranges.

I tried the following formula, but it seems to check the date only against the first range and ignores others:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(ISBETWEEN(A1, INDEX(SPLIT(SPLIT(B1, "|"), "&"), 1), INDEX(SPLIT(SPLIT(B1, "|"), "&"), 2))))`

Please help to correct the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach using LET and SUMPRODUCT

```
=LET(
  times,
    ARRAYFORMULA(
      SPLIT(
        TOCOL(
          SPLIT(B1, "|")),
        "&")),
   SUMPRODUCT(
     INDEX(times,,1)<=A1,
     INDEX(times,,2)>=A1)>0)
```

```
=LET(times,ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TOCOL(SPLIT(B1, "|")), "&")), SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(times,,1)<=A1, INDEX(times,,2)>=A1)>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,index(split(tocol(split(B1,"|")),"&")),
  if(countifs(A1,">="&index(Σ,,1),A1,"<="&index(Σ,,2)),"YES","NO"))
```

[image]

***ALTERNATE SOL_***

```js
=if(reduce(,split(B1,"|"),lambda(a,c,let(Σ,split(c,"&"),a+isbetween(A1,index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2)))))>0,"YES","NO")
```

Comment: Thank you for the formula, it works indeed.
Still, I'm curious if that can be achieved using ARRAYFORMULA and ISBETWEEN, it seems easier to understand, calculate, and modify.

Comment: *isbetween()* style solution added as well